# How to configure the MStest with the CruiseControl

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, mstest

I have cruise control setup with the Nunit test embedded and it works fine,however now I want to use the MSTest project and its result, Please advice me over the same.

Please forgive me for this small and silly question.

Thanks
Praveen

Answer (score 1):

This topic may help you a lot : [Integrating MSTest with Cruise control for multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258731/integrating-mstest-with-cruise-control-for-multiple-projects)

From the question, you can follow this tuto : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/VSTS2008_Tests_With_CCNET.aspx?display=Print

if you want to compare mstest to nunit you can check this topic : [NUnit vs Visual Studio 2010's MSTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367734/nunit-vs-visual-studio-2010s-mstest)

**Edit** : Maslow's answer in this topic may greatly helps you as well. [make ccnet self test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003741/make-ccnet-self-test)